# Get child index of text node in JavaScript or JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to figure out how I can the child number of a text element inside of a parent that may have other elements mixed in. Here is an example case:

```
<p>
    Here is a picture of something:
    <img src="something.png"/>
    Now on to other things, like <span id="highlight">this</span> thing.
</p>
```

I want to get the `<span>` element child number, which should be `3` (0-based counting). How do I go about doing this? Using JQuery's `index()` doesn't work because it only counts the elements and not the text, which would give a `1` in this case. Thank you for your time in looking at this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function getIndex(node) {
    var n = 0;

    while (node = node.previousSibling)
        n++;

    return n;
}
```

---

```
var idx = getIndex(document.getElementById("highlight"));
```

Comment: `Var n=0` and then `n--` will output negative value.

Comment: @SheikhHeera: Oh, uh yeah, Not sure why I was decrementing! Thanks.

Comment: I liked this one because I can use any arbitrary node, including text nodes. I'm using the index to select that child index later when I replace it with something completely different. To get the reference to the new replaced node, I used `$(parent).contents()[childNum]` (assuming you stored what `parent` was before you did the replace). Thanks a million!

Answer (score 2):

```
var span = document.getElementById('highlight'),
    index = Array.prototype.indexOf.call(span.parentNode.childNodes, span);
```

`Array.prototype.indexOf` will operate on the NodeList (`span.parentNode.childNodes`) as though it was an Array and get you the index of your `span` element.

You'll need a compatibility patch for `.indexOf()` if you're supporting IE8 and lower.

Comment: Why convert to an Array? If you're going to use `.call()`, then just use it directly on `.indexOf()`.

Comment: Because NodeLists don't have an indexOf method?

Comment: They also don't have a `.slice()` method.

Comment: Like this: `Array.prototype.indexOf.call(span.parentNode.childNodes, span)` NodeLists don't have an `.indexOf()` method, so you want to use `.slice()` to convert to an Array so you can use it. Trouble is that NodeLists also don't have a `.slice()` method, so you borrow it from `Array.prototype`. So instead of borrowing `.slice()` so you can convert to an Array, giving you `.indexOf()`, why not just borrow `.indexOf()` directly?

Comment: @SheikhHeera: It works fine. All `Array.prototype` methods are generic, and can work on any Array-like collection.

Comment: ...the caveat being `Array.prototype` methods that mutate the collection won't mutate an immutable collection... obviously. ;)

Answer (score 2):

jQuery has a [`.contents()`](http://api.jquery.com/contents/) method that grabs all children, including text nodes (and comment nodes). You can use that to grab the span at index 3:

```
$('p').contents()[3]; // your span!
```

Then you can use [`.index`](http://api.jquery.com/index/) to get the index based on a node reference:

```
var pContents = $('p').contents();
var span = pContents[3];  // your span
var spanIndex = pContents.index(span); // 3
```

http://jsfiddle.net/yERLu/1

Comment: That being said, I'm still very fond of the two pure js answers here, for their ingenuity. jQuery is boring sometimes! :-)

Comment: If I could choose 2 accepted answers, yours would definitely have been one of them.

Comment: This is a great way to do it. Obviously in non jquery environments an equivalent is needed to perform the `.index()` part.